# How do you access Pervasive SQL metadata tables?

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I am looking through Pervasive and on the internet and cannot find anything. I want something similar to information_schema.columns. Does that information exist in PSQL? If so, how do I access it? Thanks for taking the time to read my post =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of Pervasive.SQL you are using.  If you are using a recent version (v9 or later), you can use the system stored procedures (http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=ODBC/sysstorprocs.06.2.html) to get the column information.

If you are using PSQL v11, you can also use the System Catalog functions as documented at http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=ODBC/catalogfuncs.09.01.html.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about accessing the meta data from SQL Server via a Linked Server? So, for example, something like Call [PSQL].[DB]..PSP_COLUMNS('DB', 'Table', )?

Comment: The PSP_COLUMNS is a stored procedure so you can just "call" or "exec" it as the SQL Statement being executed.  Probably something like: select * from openquery ([PSQL],'exec PSP_COLUMNS(''DB'', ''Table'');) If that doesn't work, start a new question with what you've tried and what error you're seeing.